# Send mail using send grid api key

Tags: php, curl, sendgrid

I'm using send grid for sending mails.
This is the script I used.

```
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$params = array(
    'api_user'  => 'xxx',   // My send grid username
    'api_key'   => xxx',   // My send grid password
    'to'        => tomail,     
    'subject'   => 'sub',
    'html'      => 'message',
    'from'      => frommail,
);

$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';
$session = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
```

It's working fine and sending mails successfully.

I wan't to use send grid api key for sending mails without using the password.
I generated it from '`app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys`' got api key id and long key.

How can I use this keys from web api call. I'm replacing `api_user` and `api_key`s with newly generated `api key name` and `key` but mails are not sending.

Comment: I suggest using this https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php. You can easily install it with `composer` scroll down to the "Usage" section and you will find how to instantiate using the api key.

Comment: It's using send php library, I'm not using this. I'm using curl only.

Comment: Okay, so why not use the library then - it certainly looks easier to work with than all those raw curl functions.

Comment: Also note that Sendgrid can be used as a regular SMTP mail service, the commonly used mail libraries phpMailer or Swiftmailer will also work just fine with it.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this today as well. To add to the answer provided by @bwest:

```
$pass = 'your api token' // not the key, but the token

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';

//remove the user and password params - no longer needed
$params = array(
    'to'        => tomail,     
    'subject'   => 'sub',
    'html'      => 'message',
    'from'      => frommail,
);

$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';
$headr = array();
// set authorization header
$headr[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$pass;

$session = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// add authorization header
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);

$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
```

Answer (score 3):

To send with an API key, you need to add an `Authorization` header to your request. It is an HTTP Basic auth header, meaning it is in the format `username:password`, base64 encoded, as a bearer token. You can [see an example](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Send/api_keys.html#-Via-HTTP) in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Send Grid php library where I can use username and password OR just the API Key.

Try removing the `api_user` line and using the api key with `api_key`. It should work.

For more info: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/php.html

Comment: Tried this, but not getting mail to my inbox/spam.

Comment: Check if you have any overlapping variables. For example, i had 2 $EMAIL set (1 for email address and another for sendgrid)

Answer (score 0):

Using the API key with the `Autorization: Bearer key` header works.